# unpersist() in spark gives Serialization Exception

Tags: apache-spark

I'm broadcasting a hashmap and also able to retrieve it's value at the executor nodes. But when I try to unpersist() this broadcasted hashmap inside the call() method of a transformation function, I get following Exception:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Error sending message [message = RemoveBroadcast(6,false)]
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise, value: scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@453ec620)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:40)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.serialize(NettyRpcEnv.scala:255)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.RemoteNettyRpcCallContext.send(NettyRpcCallContext.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcCallContext.reply(NettyRpcCallContext.scala:32)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint$$anonfun$receiveAndReply$1.applyOrElse(BlockManagerMasterEndpoint.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Inbox$$anonfun$process$1.apply$mcV$sp(Inbox.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Inbox.safelyCall(Inbox.scala:204)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Inbox.process(Inbox.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Dispatcher$MessageLoop.run(Dispatcher.scala:215)
```

The code is as follows:

public class SprinterKafkaStream implements Serializable
{

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 172210347397861748L;

/* KAFKA Parameters for streaming interface */
 Map<String, String> inputKafkaParams = null;


Broadcast<HashMap<String, Double>> hamperrateLookupBroadcast = null;    

static JavaStreamingContext jsc ;
private  Config appConfig ;
private static Broadcast<HashMap<String, KafkaProducerSer>> appWiseKafkaProducerSerBroadcast = null;
private  ProcessRDD processor;


changeRefDataRequest.foreachRDD(new VoidFunction<JavaRDD<String>>() { 

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private AWPEvent event;

    @Override
    public void call(JavaRDD<String> rdd) throws Exception 
    {
        /*Kafka producer instance to connect to response topic*/
        final KafkaProducerSer producer = appWiseKafkaProducerSerBroadcast.getValue().get(appConfig.getAppId());
        SprinterLogger.infoLog_and_Console("Producer " + producer.toString());
        rdd.foreachPartition(new VoidFunction<Iterator<String>>() { //exception issue
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                @Override
                public void call(Iterator<String> changeReqItr) throws Exception 
                {


                    if(changeReqItr != null) 
                    {

                        while(changeReqItr.hasNext()) 
                        {
                            try 
                            {
                                String request = changeReqItr.next();
                                SprinterLogger.infoLog_and_Console("****Request****" + request);

                                if(request !=null) 
                                {
                                 event = AWPXmlParser.getReferenceDataRefreshInfo(request);
                                 SprinterLogger.infoLog_and_Console("****AWPevent****" + event);
                                 //check for application id & instance name 
                                //if ((event.getAppID().equals(appConfig.getAppId())) && (event.getProcessID().startsWith(appConfig.getInstanceName()))) 

                                    if ((event.getAppID().equals(appConfig.getAppId())) && (event.getProcessID().startsWith(appConfig.getRegion()))) 
                                    {
                                        Process process = event.getProcess();
                                        SprinterLogger.infoLog_and_Console("Process created" + process.isInput());
                                        if (process.isInput()) 
                                        {
                                            List<Attribute> attributes = process.getAttributes();
                                            if(attributes.isEmpty())
                                            {
                                                SprinterLogger.infoLog_and_Console("Attributes List is empty");
                                            }

                                            for (Attribute attribute : attributes) 
                                            {

                                                SprinterLogger.infoLog_and_Console("Attribute info: " + attribute.getName().toString() + " " + attribute.getType().toString() + " " + attribute.getValue().toString());

                                                if (CommonPropertiesConstants.HAMPERRATE_CHANGE_ATTR_NAME.equals(attribute.getName())) 
                                            {
                                                SprinterLogger.infoLog_and_Console("Inside hamper rate update");

                                                Set set = hamperrateLookupBroadcast.value().entrySet();
                                                Iterator iterator = set.iterator();
                                                while(iterator.hasNext()) 
                                                {
                                                     Map.Entry mentry = (Map.Entry)iterator.next();
                                                     SprinterLogger.infoLog_and_Console("Hamperrate key is: "+ mentry.getKey().toString() + " and Value is: ");
                                                     SprinterLogger.infoLog_and_Console(mentry.getValue().toString());
                                                 }
                                                hamperrateLookupBroadcast.unpersist(); //exception hamperrateLookupBroadcast
                                                SprinterLogger.infoLog_and_Console("UNPERSISTED");
                                                HashMap<String, Double> hamperrateLookupnMaps=HamperRateLookups.loadHamperRateData(attribute.getValue());
                                                hamperrateLookupBroadcast=jsc.sparkContext().broadcast(hamperrateLookupnMaps);
                                                processor.updateHamperRateLookupBroadcast(hamperrateLookupBroadcast);
                                                SprinterLogger.infoLog_and_Console("\n Refreshing Hamper rate file for application id:"+event.getAppID()+", instance:"+event.getProcessID()+" : DONE\n");



                                            }
```

}

Here, Im trying to unpersist the broadcasted reference data and then rebroadcast it with updated data.

Could somebody please help?

Comment: Can you post the minimal code that yields this error in your environment?

Comment: Hey, I have added the code in the question.